# Android RecyclerView with gridlayout smoothScrollTo() speed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager.

If I run the code

```
recycler.smoothScrollTo(adapter.getItemCount())
```

the recycler scrolls really fast to the last element. I tried some solutions on Stackoverflow to make the scrolling slower, but all apply to Linearlayoutmanager not Gridlayoutmanager.

Any help?

Comment: Hello Mo Dev, welcome to SO! *Where* are you doing this call? Did you try to `recycler.post(new Runnable() { recycler.smooth... } )` instead? (you get the idea)

Comment: Hello @Martin. I call this function from a button hover. I tried yes this method using a Handler and a Runnable but no hope :(

Comment: @Amninder how should this help me? as it's dealing with the position of the target, however I'm asking about the SPEED of scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simple working solution currently is still implementing a timer then working with it.

```
        final CountDownTimer scrollUp_timer = new CountDownTimer(50000, 30) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (layoutManager != null && layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() != 0) searchRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()-1);
        }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                try{
                }catch(Exception e){
                // log
                }
            }
        };

        scrollUp.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
            layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)searchRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
            int action = dragEvent.getAction();
            if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED) {
                scrollUp_timer.start();

            } else if (action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) {
                searchRecyclerView.scrollBy(0,0);
                scrollUp_timer.cancel();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure what your problem is. But I am lucky enough to have a very simple GridLayoutManager recyclerview demo out there, very small sample project. I created a `so` branch and added a button that does the same you do.

Look it up: https://github.com/Gryzor/GridToShowAds/compare/so?expand=1

`.setOnClickListener { mainRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(data.size) }`

And that alone just works.

Check the source code, it's a very simple sample for something unrelated, but happens to have a RV with a Grid Layout :)

#### UPDATE

What you actual want is to control the *Speed* at which the recyclerView scrolls. Ok.

1. It's not the RecyclerView that drives the scroll, it's actually the `LayoutManager` that does. How so?

If you look at RV's source code...

```
public void smoothScrollToPosition(int position) {

    ...

    mLayout.smoothScrollToPosition(this, mState, position);
}
```

So it ends up calling `mLayout`. What is this?

`@VisibleForTesting LayoutManager mLayout;`

So, your LayoutManager#smoothScroll... method is used.

Decompiling now GridLayoutManager for *science*:

```
@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state,
        int position) {
    LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller =
            new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
    linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
}
```

<sub>*note: this method is actually in `LinearLayoutManager` because `GridLayoutManager` is a subclass and it doesn't override the method*</sub>

A `LinearSmoothScroller`!; no parameter to specify the speed though...

Look at it:

```
public class LinearSmoothScroller extends RecyclerView.SmoothScroller {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 25f;
    private static final int TARGET_SEEK_SCROLL_DISTANCE_PX = 10000;
...

}
```

This class has a `start()` method described as:
`* Starts a smooth scroll for the given target position.`

So who calls this?

The mLayout.smoothScrollToPosition method does at the end in the `startSmoothScroll(...)` call.

`public void startSmoothScroll(SmoothScroller smoothScroller) {`

`Starts a smooth scroll using the provided {@link SmoothScroller}.`

```
mSmoothScroller.start(mRecyclerView, this);
```

So... in lieu of all this, the answer to your question is:

You need to create your extension of GridLayoutManager by subclassing it, and in it, override the `smoothScrollToPosition` method, to provide your own Scroller logic.

Thread carefully though, LayoutManagers are not the "simplest" classes of all time and they can be quite complicated to master.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have a very similar code and it's also working fine (talking about scrolling to the desired last element) but my problem is its SPEED as it scrolls really fast to the desired element (this is the normal speed for this function) however I'm looking for a way to make this scrolling effect slower than the default one.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed updated answer, however I find it a bit above my current programming abilities :D

Answer (score 0):

You can extend:

```
class CSCustomRecyclerSmoothScroller(context: Context, speed: Float = 0.2f)
    : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
    override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float = speed
}
```

And use it like:

```
val shortAnimationDuration =
            view.resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime)

val scroller = CSCustomRecyclerSmoothScroller(this, speed = 0.15)
scroller.targetPosition = position
view.postDelayed({
    layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(scroller)
}, shortAnimationDuration.toLong())
```

`postDelayed` can be necessary in some cases but maybe not in all.

I use similar code with GridLayoutManager I just tried to extract relevant parts from my way of writing things.